# How do you convert from a New Google Maps share link to an iframe embed html?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, url, iframe, embed

In my app users can just paste a link to something like a youtube or vimeo video or some soundcloud audio and it then figures out how to embed that via oembed.

So if you paste the link to a video copied from your address bar it can figure it out. If you paste the share link that the apps kick out in their "share dialogs", it works too. If you paste the iframe embed code I can parse that and check it against a whitelist and you get exactly the same thing again.

I want to add Google Maps embedding too, but it doesn't support oembed. Furthermore, you now get the "classic" (or old) Google Maps, but you also get the new google maps. (To complicate things further, you also get google maps engine, but let's ignore that one for now..)

With classic google maps it is trivial to convert from a share link to the iframe embed URL because it essentially has the same URL parameters, you just add an output=embed URL parameter so that Google will output the embed layout rather than the desktop site layout.

The new google maps isn't that simple. The share link's parameters are different enough from the embed link's parameters that you can't just do a simple "prefix conversion" and get something usable out.

What I mean by that is that this is a share URL:

```
https://www.google.com/maps/preview#!data=!1m4!1m3!1d62859!2d-99.1363591!3d19.4492142
```

and this is the embed iframe's src for the same map:

```
https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m12!1m3!1d60194.35709853462!2d-99.1363591!3d19.4492142!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!5e0!3m2!1sen!2s!4v1390394813768
```

If you just change the prefix from `https://www.google.com/maps/preview#!data=` to `https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=` or back it doesn't work.

It looks like some of the parameters in there are the same, but clearly there's much more to the embed one.

Is there documentation or code or examples or *something* out there that explains how this works? I've looked everywhere I could think of and the closest I can find is [iframely's google maps plugin](https://github.com/itteco/iframely/blob/b24148d4762a851d73f313e90950952c82d5e2c9/plugins/domains/maps.google.com.js), but they only convert [some of the parameters](https://github.com/itteco/iframely/issues/27) and then they use the old Google Maps' embed. I would prefer to use the more minimal new one, at least when someone pasted a link or embed for the new google maps.

## tl;dr

I want to convert

```
https://www.google.com/maps/preview#!data=!1m4!1m3!1d62859!2d-99.1363591!3d19.4492142
```

to

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m12!1m3!1d60194.35709853462!2d-99.1363591!3d19.4492142!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!5e0!3m2!1sen!2s!4v1390394813768" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0"></iframe>
```

*or*

```
https://www.google.com/maps/preview#!data=!1m4!1m3!1d316784!2d9.927821!3d53.558572!4m12!2m11!1m10!1s0x0%3A0x4263df27bd63aa0!3m8!1m3!1d303354!2d9.927821!3d53.558572!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1
```

to

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m17!1m12!1m3!1d303354.2311276431!2d9.927821!3d53.558572!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m2!1m1!1s0x0%3A0x4263df27bd63aa0!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sus!4v1390395234903" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0"></iframe>
```

and make it work as if Google Maps supported oembed. I realise the iframe code has more information, but the only attributes that are useful to me are width and height to get the aspect ratio and src. I suspect that most of the url parameters can just be guessed or defaulted as I'm only really interested in things like the coordinates and the zoom level.

Comment: Hey man, having the exact same issue now. Did you have any luck?

Answer (score 0):

I can't see a way to do it using one of your own saved maps. However it is possible using a place name, coordinates or search results:

Show a single place:

```
<iframe width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=AIzaSyD4iE2xVSpkLLOXoyqT-RuPwURN3ddScAI&amp;q=Space+Needle,Seattle+WA">
```

Coordinates:

```
<iframe width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/view?key=AIzaSyD4iE2xVSpkLLOXoyqT-RuPwURN3ddScAI&amp;center=-33.8569,151.2152&amp;zoom=18&amp;maptype=satellite"></iframe>
```

Show search results:

```
<iframe width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/search?key=AIzaSyD4iE2xVSpkLLOXoyqT-RuPwURN3ddScAI&amp;q=record+stores+in+Seattle"></iframe>
```